# CORS issue in Axios

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios

I'am Trying to get Data from another source via axios and it causes a CORS issue

```
if (imgUrl) {
axios
.get(proxyUrl + imgUrl, {
headers: {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
 },
 })
 .then((response) => {
 console.log("response inside orderdetailPageCOntainer", response)
 this.setState({binaryData: response.headers["x-final-url"]}, () => 
 console.log("bbbbbbbb",this.state. binaryData));
 });
 // fetch(proxyUrl + imgUrl)
 //   .then(response => response.text())
 //   .then(contents => console.log("contents", contents))
 //   .catch(() => console.log(`Can’t access ${imgUrl} response. Blocked 
 by browser?`));
 }
```

Comment: The code you commented is not properly comment. `by broswer?'));` you missed that to comment. Also do share your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps,

1) First check whether your Api is up.

2) Try to do the request via a postman tool. Cors do not apply for requests made via postman.

3) If the request is successful via postman, then you Api is good. Issue is cors.

4) Then add your front end app's domain as a allowed origin in you Api configuration. They way doing it depends on your Api technology. Read the doc on that.

5) there is no use of the the request Header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*". At the client side.

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a standard that allows a server to relax the same-origin policy. This is used to explicitly allow some cross-origin requests while rejecting others.

So maybe the other server rejecting loading resources from other domains.